# Code for finding string between "" in a data structure

Tags: c++

I need help to solve the following:

Lets say I have the number 70368 in int var and that I want to find the corresponding string "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_FLT" in the structure below and load it ( including the "") to a 
char* event variable

The code solution must work for any number lenght between 1 to 5.

```
struct NameOffset TestEvents[] = {

    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST1", 70387 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST1", 70387 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST2", 70512 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST2", 70512 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MASK_BOOM_SWITCH", 70385 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_FLT", 70368 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF1", 70510 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF2", 70511 },
 };
```

The table is in real very long, this is just a few lines to show the structure.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? If you don't know anything else, can't you use simple `for` loop, and compare each item with the specific item you're looking for?

Comment: Note that the C++ program doesn't see the quotes. If you want to have them you'll need to add them to the string, e.g. using "\"foo\"". Also, have a look at `std::map<...>` or `std::unordered_map<...>`.

Comment: What should be the return value, in case the number is present more than once? The first occurence? The second occurence? Any of them? Also how many elements will your final array hold? Just these few, or a very large number?

Comment: I believe the OP has mistakenly entered the events 70387 and 70512 twice each, and that the codes are unique. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the fields of `struct NameOffset` are `Name` and `Offset`, you can find a match using a loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != sizeof(TestEvents)/sizeof(struct NameOffset) ; i++) {
    if (PmdgEvents[i].Offset == intVar) {
        printf("%s\n", PmdgEvents[i].Name);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a 1>IOCPClient.cpp(277): error C2070: 'NameOffset []': illegal sizeof operand with your code.

Comment: @user1288615 `sizeof(TestEvents)/sizeof(struct NameOffset)` detects the number of elements of your array. If you know how many items you have, use that number instead.

Answer (score 0):

The brute-force approach is to use a loop and compare the second struct member to identigfy the right struct.

If the code will be executed regularly, you should use a `unordered_map`: load the data to a `unordered_map<int, string>` (or `char *` instead of `string` if you like) and then use

```
event_map[code];
```

to access the string.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct NameOffset {
    const char *event;
    int code;
};

struct NameOffset TestEvents[] = {
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST1", 70387 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST2", 70512 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MASK_BOOM_SWITCH", 70385 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_FLT", 70368 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF1", 70510 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF2", 70511 },
 };

#define N_ELEMENTS (sizeof(TestEvents) / sizeof(NameOffset))

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, const char *> event_map;
    for (NameOffset *it = TestEvents, *it_end = TestEvents + N_ELEMENTS;
            it != it_end; ++it) {
        event_map[it->code] = it->event;
    }

    cout << event_map[70387] << endl;
    cout << event_map[70512] << endl;
    cout << event_map[70385] << endl;
    cout << event_map[70368] << endl;
    cout << event_map[70510] << endl;
    cout << event_map[70511] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map of `<int,string>` and then index the map with the corresponding value you want to search

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
using namespace std;    
int main (){    
    std::pair<int,string> TestEvents[] = {
    make_pair( 70387,"EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST1"  ),
    make_pair( 70???,"EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST1"  ),
    make_pair( 70512,"EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST2"  ),
    make_pair( 70512,"EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST2"  ),
    make_pair(  70385, "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MASK_BOOM_SWITCH" ),
    make_pair( 70368,"EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_FLT"  ),
    make_pair( 70510,"EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF1"  ),
    make_pair( 70511,"EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF2"  )
    };
    map<int,string> mapTestEvents(TestEvents,TestEvents + sizeof TestEvents / sizeof TestEvents[0]);
    int var = 70368;
    const char* event = mapTestEvents[var].c_str();
    return 0;
    }
```

Please note, I assume the integer value is unique else the whole problem statement would be void.

And yet another way to do it using std::sort and std::lower_bound

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct NameOffset {
    string name;
    int offset;
    };
NameOffset TestEvents[] = {

    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST1", 70387 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST1", 70387 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST2", 70512 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_LAST2", 70512 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MASK_BOOM_SWITCH", 70385 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_FLT", 70368 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF1", 70510 },
    { "EVT_ACP_CAPT_MIC_HF2", 70511 },
    };
bool CompareByEvent(NameOffset const& lhs, NameOffset const& rhs) {
    return lhs.offset < rhs.offset;
    }
int main (){
    sort(TestEvents,TestEvents + sizeof TestEvents / sizeof TestEvents[0], &CompareByEvent);
    NameOffset var = {"",70510};
    const char* event =lower_bound(TestEvents,TestEvents + sizeof TestEvents / sizeof TestEvents[0], var,&CompareByEvent)->name.c_str();
    return 0;
    }
```